# Sonata User Bundle error on profile edit

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I configure a symfony 2.7 installation with the lasted sonata admin and sonata user bundles. My backend work well, also work /profile page, but I'm getting this error in /profile/edit-profile and /profile/edit-authentication :

```
Unable to find template "MopaBootstrapBundle:Form:fields.html.twig" in SonataUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword_content.html.twig at line 2.
```

this is my config.yml

```
fos_user:
    ...
    profile:
        form:
            type:               fos_user_profile
            handler:            fos_user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               fos_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Authentication]

sonata_user:
    ...
    profile:  # Profile Form (firstname, lastname, etc ...)
        form:
            type:               sonata_user_profile
            handler:            sonata.user.profile.form.handler.default
            name:               sonata_user_profile_form
            validation_groups:  [Profile]
```

and some routes:

```
sonata_user_resetting:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_resetting_1.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

sonata_user_profile:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_profile_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile

sonata_user_change_password:
    resource: "@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_change_password_1.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

Also look for that template mention in that twig file but I don't see it.
Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution installing [mopa bootsrap bundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle) and configure it.